# Google Photos - is it possible to autosync it with PC?

Tags: google-photos

so I know that since 2019 there have been some changes so the Google Drive app no longer works with Photos (somehow). If I setup Google Drive to mirror my files, weirdly it works the way that all photos and videos until 2019 get downloaded into Google Photos folder, but not any newer ones. Is there any way to sync between Google Photos and my PC? Or no longer there is and sync is possible only with mobile phones now?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sadly, as you indicate, there is no Google-supported auto-sync method anymore, since 2019.  [Google support info](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089).  Regardless, there are several third-party service providers that support migrating files from one cloud storage provider to another.  However, since I'm unfamiliar with them (lack of trust), I will not give them any free publicity (for fear of privacy and security concerns).

Comment: thanks. What about some addons which might be able to mass download files from Google Photos?...I see it is Google Takeout. The resulting folders are kind of a mess though I think :-\